# in logical replication from standby host, create subscription command hangs

Tags: postgresql, replication

In following setup, create subscription command hangs and there is no error in logs

```
HOST1          --> HOST2                --> HOST3
Master         --> phsyical replication --> logical replication
Version 16.1   --> Version 16.1         --> Version 16.2
```

some addtional information is

- HOST1 and HOST2 almost in sync while run create subscription command
- created publication on HOST1, checked publication on HOST2 and it's ok
- run select pg_log_standby_snapshot() and checkpoint on HOST1  before create subscription
- I can see logical replication slot in HOST2 but create subscription command is not finished yet

on HOST2

```
postgres=# select * from pg_replication_slots ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+-------------
slot_name           | lrep_slot
plugin              | pgoutput
slot_type           | logical
datoid              | 13753820
database            | proddb
temporary           | f
active              | t
active_pid          | 495948
xmin                | 
catalog_xmin        | 29726257
restart_lsn         | AC8/19059C00
confirmed_flush_lsn | 
wal_status          | reserved
safe_wal_size       | 
two_phase           | f
conflicting         | f

proddb=# \dRp
List of publications
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------
Name       | pubmedas8
Owner      | postgres
All tables | f
Inserts    | t
Updates    | t
Deletes    | t
Truncates  | t
Via root   | f

proddb=# select pid, backend_xid, backend_xmin, wait_event, wait_event_type, query  from pg_stat_activity ;
  pid   | backend_xid | backend_xmin |    wait_event     | wait_event_type |                                               query                                                
--------+-------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 495948 |             |              |                   |                 | CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT "lrep_slot" LOGICAL pgoutput (SNAPSHOT 'nothing')
 508553 |             |     29666602 |                   |                 | select pid, backend_xid, backend_xmin, wait_event, wait_event_type, query  from pg_stat_activity ;
 495929 |             |              | RecoveryWalStream | Activity        | 
 495928 |             |              | BgWriterMain      | Activity        | 
 495927 |             |              | CheckpointerMain  | Activity        | 
 495930 |             |              | WalReceiverMain   | Activity        | 
(6 rows)

proddb=# select locktype, pid, mode from pg_locks;
  locktype  |  pid   |      mode       
------------+--------+-----------------
 relation   | 508553 | AccessShareLock
 virtualxid | 508553 | ExclusiveLock
 virtualxid | 495929 | ExclusiveLock
```

Comment: Try calling `pg_log_standby_snapshot()` after you have started `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe just called, no change

Comment: No idea then. Seems like `CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT` is busy (no wait events).